# Trying to find a percent of a categorical Column

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to figure out the percentage of a categorical column. 
There are 5 Categories - Home, Home Health, SNF, Other, Unknown

I want to find the percent of Home & Home Health divided by total number categories. I am a bit of a rookie and am not quiet sure how to do this.

My query looks something like this.

```
SELECT Location
FROM Database
Where (Location = Home or Home Health / Count(Location))
```

Comment: Please give example data and desired results

Comment: Hi @MartinSmith    I want 1 output that say something like:  80% of records have "Home or Home Health" as a location.   Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can count conditionally and divide with a full count:

```
Select 100.0 * count( case when <condition> then 1 end)  / count (1)     
from ...
```

Comment: You need an `ELSE` condition in that `CASE` statement, or the entire statement will return `NULL`

Comment: @Athur, no the `ELSE` is no needed. On the contrary, it will cause harm. The point of this code is that the default for case expressions is `ELSE NULL` and nulls are not counted by `COUNT()`.

Comment: And it's a `CASE` expression, not a statement.

Comment: @Arthur, that's intentional, only count the rows that meed the <condition>.

Comment: My mistake. I'm used to doing a `SUM(CASE WHEN <condition> THEN 1 ELSE 0)` instead of `COUNT`.